# How to troubleshoot fan speed in Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon?

Tags: linux-mint, fan

I installed Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon over Windows 8 recently on an Acer Aspire E1-570.

http://www.acer.com.au/ac/en/AU/content/model/NX.MEPSA.004

Everything seems to be working fine, however I notice that my fan seems to be on at high speed a lot of the time.

Can someone please tell me definitive troubleshooting steps that are relevant to this distro.

Also if there are commands that I can run to get the relevant system information required to troubleshoot the issue it would be great to know these too.

**Edit**

In case it is relevant, the screen brightness applet control wasn't working so I followed steps below - perhaps that altered something?

```
me@computer ~ $ ls /sys/class/backlight/
acpi_video0  intel_backlight
sudo touch /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf

and then added this to the file:

Section "Device"
Identifier  "card0"
Driver      "intel"
Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"EndSection
```

http://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/

`Sensors` also seems to be mentioned in other posts so I typed it into the command and this was the output:

```
me@computer ~ $ sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +44.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:         +44.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:         +44.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
```

**More System Information**

```
me@computer ~ $ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor
ondemand

me@computer ~ $ inxi -Fxz
System:    Host: computer Kernel: 3.13.0-24-generic x86_64 (64 bit, gcc: 4.8.2)
```

[image]
Right-click > "Open image in new tab" to see image at full size.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the output of `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor`, your graphics card and the driver you are using to control it.

Comment: Requested information added.

Comment: Did you install something like zram? or, alternatively, did you followed some post installation guide that promised you to speed up your PC changing, for instance, the swap?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran in similar difficulties on a different computer model, perhaps what follows can helps you but it may be different on your computer.

You may check for the cooling device state of the fan. This script will show the cooling devices names, types and status.

```
for a in /sys/devices/virtual/thermal/cooling_device*
do 
    echo $(basename $a) $(cat $a/type) $(cat $a/cur_state)
done
```

On my computer :

```
cooling_device0 Fan 0
cooling_device1 Fan 0
cooling_device2 Fan 0
cooling_device3 Fan 1
cooling_device4 Fan 1
cooling_device5 Processor 0
cooling_device6 Processor 0
cooling_device7 LCD 0
```

In real there is only one fan on my computer. The `cooling_device* Fan` are different vue of the same fan.

This is how it works on my computer :

When /`sys/class/thermal/cooling_device4/cur_state` is set to **1** the fan management is activated.  The other `/sys/class/thermal/cooling_device[0123]/cur_stat` will see their value automatically changing from **0** to **1** depending on the temperature.
For instance at 60°C `cooling_device3/cur_state`t is set to **1**.

When /`sys/class/thermal/cooling_device4/cur_state` is set to **0** the thermal management is stopped. The fan is stopped and when the computer reach 80°C the fan is run at high speed until the computer cools down to bellow 50°C.

This is what I do to activate the thermal management:

```
echo 1 > /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device4/cur_state
```

Forcing **1** to the other `cooling_devices* Fan` had no effect.

I put it in a service to have it activated at boot and after a "suspend/resume".

- *Don't force the status on the **non Fan** devices I don't know what it can do.*
- *If you change a **Fan** state, monitor the temperature at different activity level*

Answer (score 0):

first install auto-cpufreq. auto-cpufreq it's an automatic CPU speed and power optimizer for Linux based on active monitoring of laptop's battery state, CPU usage, CPU temperature and system load.

```
git clone https://github.com/AdnanHodzic/auto-cpufreq.git

cd auto-cpufreq 

sudo ./auto-cpufreq-installer
```

then run `auto-cpufreq --help` for more help, but the default config should be enough then start the daemon `systemctl enable --now auto-cpufreq.service` reboot after starting the daemon and your fans should be on low now [image: example image]